# Display a local image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a problem displaying an image in WPF. The problem is that I add the image into the Grid and I can not actually see the image. I can see the place where the image is, but not the image itself (check the image below):
[image]

Here is my code:

View:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Visible">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Image Height="25" Width="50" Source="{Binding Path=ImageArticle}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Here I take the path and add it:

```
ContinueArticle ca = new ContinueArticle();
string ImagePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"C:\iClipIT\Thumbs\" + ClipID;
ca.ImageArticle = ImagePath;
atlist.Add(ca);
```

And here I create the object and the getters and setters:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ArticleImageProperty
    = DependencyProperty.Register("ArticleImage", typeof(string), typeof(ContinueArticle));

public string ImageArticle
{
    get
    {
        return (string)GetValue(ArticleImageProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ArticleImageProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong? I read a lot about this and I can't find the problem.

Comment: `Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"C:\iClipIT\Thumbs\"` doesn't make sense. It should probably be `string ImagePath = @"C:\iClipIT\Thumbs\" + ClipID;`

Comment: Besides that it isn't clear why `ImageArticle` is a dependency property. It seems to be a view model property, and the source but not the target of a binding. Usually view models don't (need to) have dependency properties.

Comment: Bind a bitmap property from your viewModel, u dont need a Dependency property. Y hv u created "ArticleImageProperty"?

Comment: Does your column contains same image for all cells?

Comment: I just found out that was exactly the problem. The Path was incorrect so it was creating the spot but not actually adding the image. As I changed it, it works perfectly! Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a Image in the DataGridTemplateColumn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432313/add-a-image-in-the-datagridtemplatecolumn)